# Car breakdown database and diagnostic trouble codes, that caused a breakdown

Tags: data-request, transportation, cars

I didn't found source of the data in which there could be information about car breakdowns, the causes of failure and, possible, diagnostic trouble codes(DTC). Can your help me with this problem?